# How to read RGB values of cell background color from XSSFCellStyle using Apache Poi in Java

Tags: colors, apache-poi, cell, xssf

I need to read RGB values of Excel cell background color from XSSFCellStyle.
I tried below mentioned code. It didn't work.

```
byte[] rgb1 = excelCellStyle.getFillForegroundXSSFColor().getRGB();
byte[] rgb2 = excelCellStyle.getFillForegroundXSSFColor().getCTColor().getRgb();
```

This code returning [79, -127, -67] as RGB values but actual RGB values are [220, 230, 241]. How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

```
    XSSFColor xssfColorF = cell.getFillForegroundColorColor();
    int[] bg_RGB = new int[] {255, 255, 255};
    if(xssfColorF != null)
    {
        byte[] xssfColorF_tint = xssfColorF.getRGBWithTint();
        bg_RGB = new int[xssfColorF_tint.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < xssfColorF_tint.length; i++) {
            bg_RGB[i] = Byte.toUnsignedInt(xssfColorF_tint[i]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you couldn't get correct color values. At first, I thought those values may corresponds to signed bytes but they aren't. I used getFillForegroundColorColor() function to extract color value of a cell. I'm sharing a code piece that you can use. Still it returns negative rgb values but we should convert it to unsignedInt for that reason I converted them after retrieving RGB values.

```
XSSFColor fillForegroundColorColor = (XSSFColor) cell.getCellStyle().getFillForegroundColorColor();
byte[] rgb = fillForegroundColorColor.getRGB();
int[] rgbInt = new int[rgb.length];
for(int i = 0; i<rgb.length; i++) {
    rgbInt[i] = Byte.toUnsignedInt(rgb[i]);
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rgbInt));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.Your code is doing good. But, I am having Excel template, in template the cell background values are in RGB [220, 230, 241]. After converting RGB values [79, -127, -67] using your code it giving [79, 129, 189]. RGB values are not matching with excel sheet color palette and code output.

Comment: Hi Sathishkumar, can you share the file you are working on so that I can try why we cannot get the correct values? Also, did you use only converting part or the whole code? Because I used cell.getCellStyle().getFillForegroundColorColor() function to retrieve color information.

Comment: My usecase is copying Excel cell background color into PDF Cell background. Here is my code:                                                                                                           `XSSFColor xssfColorF = excelCell.getFillForegroundColorColor();                    
String bg_strRGB = xssfColorF.getCTColor().getDomNode().getAttributes().getNamedItem("rgb").getNodeValue();                                                                         
pdfCell.setBackgroundColor(new BaseColor(Color.decode("#" + bg_strRGB)));`

Comment: I tried for different colors and my code works properly, I strongly suggest you to use above code sample that I shared if you cannot solve with your methods.

Comment: Thanks. @Halil                                                                                                                          
   `String colorStr= "#" + excelCell.getFillForegroundColorColor().getARGBHex();         
    Integer r = Integer.valueOf(colorStr.substring( 1, 3 ), 16);
    Integer g = Integer.valueOf(colorStr.substring( 3, 5 ), 16);
    Integer b = Integer.valueOf(colorStr.substring( 5, 7 ), 16);`